# Erorr al insertar un dato. sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: tags.name

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo la siguiente tabla la cual contiene nombres de etiquetas (tags) y un identificador para cada uno:

```
public static final String TABLE_CREATE_TAGS =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TAGS + " (" +
                COLUMN_TAG_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                COLUMN_TAG_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE "+
                ")";
```

Solamente quiero insertar etiquetas que no están en la `base de datos`. Por eso si recibo un `-1` a la hora de realizar el `insert` recojo el `id`de la etiqueta.

La app no se cuelga y funciona todo correctamente pero en el `log`recibo un error.

El insert lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TAG_NAME, tag);

// insert row
long id = database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS, null, values);

if(id == -1){ // El tag ya existe. Tenemos que pillar su verdadero id
   id = getTagId(tag);
 }
```

El error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: tags.name (code 2067)
```

Comment: Tu campo Nombre es `UNIQUE` eso significa que vas a tener problemas cuando no se cumpla ese constraint, osea no puedes ingresar un nombre igual a otro que ya hallas registrado. Sería mejor que le quites en `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero he editado la respuesta de @pablo con el código correcto. Al quitar el `UNIQUE` se esta perdiendo consistencia de la base de datos, ya que no deseo que ese nombre se repita en la bd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes definido el campo name como único, aunque cambies el valor del campo Id, si no modificas el nombre va a seguir dando error si lo insertas dos veces.

La manera correcta de realizar el insert es comprobando antes si existe o no.

```
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TAG_NAME, tag);
            if(existTag(tag)){ // El tag ya existe. Tenemos que pillar su verdadero id
                id = getTagId(tag);

            }else{
                // insert row
                id = database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS, null, values);
            }
            tagsIdsList.add(id);
```

El metodo `existTag`:

```
public boolean existTag(String tag){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_TAGS, idColumnsTags, "name=?", new String[]  { tag }, null, null, null);
    return (cursor.getCount() >0);
}
```

Comment: Sí, pero yo pensaba que si el campo name es el mismo devolvía -1 sin ningún error. Pero parece que estoy equivocado.

Comment: Devuelve -1, sí, pero el error de BD se sigue produciendo.